# How can I convert my flash application viewport into a video stream?

Tags: flash, flash-builder, flash-video

I have a interactive flash application where I can click on menus and do stuff with it. Is it possible to capture the whole viewport which involves expanding menus and stuff and turn it into a video stream in flash?

Answer (score 0):

Na, but use this: http://www.techsmith.com/camtasia/?gclid=CPPWtOXxmKkCFQrgbgod9WiBug